# Code with enumerate and for loop is giving me repetitive result on first letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me understand why this code is returning the first letter twice? The goal is to capitalize the first and fourth letter of the string.

```
def old_macdonald(name):
    newname=''
    for i,letter in enumerate(name):
        if i==0:
            newname+=letter.upper()
        if i==3:
            newname+=letter.upper()
        else:
            newname+=letter
    return newname

old_macdonald('Macdonald')
```

Output:

```
MMacDonald  # when it should be MacDonald instead of MM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `if` statement should be an `elif`:

```
def old_macdonald(name):
    newname=''
    for i,letter in enumerate(name):
        if i==0:
            newname+=letter.upper()
        elif i==3:
            newname+=letter.upper()
        else:
            newname+=letter
    return newname

old_macdonald('Macdonald') # 'MacDonald'
```

In your code, on the first letter, the first `if` statement runs, appends a letter, moves to the second `if` statement, fails, moves to the `else` statement, and appends another letter, thus duplicating the first letter. Changing the second `if` to an `elif`, you guarantee that only one of the three blocks will execute.

Comment: I have no idea kerwei... I up-voted and chose this as my answer... Thank you so much Tomothy32!!!

Comment: @Sophie No problem, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

As Tomothy mentioned, the problem is stacking the conditions of `if ... else` statements in python and the way it is interpreted.

```
   if i==0:                       
        newname+=letter.upper()     #When i is 0 newname wil be changed to `M`
   if i==3:                        # Here i is still 0 but the condition fails
        newname+=letter.upper()
   else:                           # This is an else statement after a filed if, so it will be executed
        newname+=letter             # Here i is still 0 and this part executes and causes duplication
```

`elif` as others mentioned will solve your problem, telling python that you want `if`, `elif`, and `else` to be evaluated as a single logical unit not separately.

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
def old_macdonald(name):
   newname=''
   for i,letter in enumerate(name):
       if i==0:
           newname+=letter.upper()
       if i==3:
           newname+=letter.upper()
       if i not in [0,3]:
           newname+=letter

   return newname
print(old_macdonald('Macdonald'))
```

Output:

```
MacDonald
```

Comment: @Tomothy32 Yup, you took the best one :-)